# How to add auto calculation for the fields

Tags: javascript

### html code

```
<td><input type="text" id="qty" name="data[User][qua][1][qty]" onkeyup="add_number()" value="" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE QTY')"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="amount" name="data[User][qua][1][amount]" onkeyup="add_number()" value="" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE AMOUNT')"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="dis" name="data[User][qua][1][dis]" onkeyup="add_number()" value="0"  required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE DISCOUNT')"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="total" name="data[User][qua][1][total]" value=""  required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE TOTAL')"/></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="addNewQualification()" class="add_btn" style="font-size:20px;">+</button></td>
```

For these fields i have written one functionality i.e add_number().To get auto calculation

```
function add_number() {

            var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty").value);
            var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value);
            var third_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("dis").value);

            var result = first_number * second_number;
            var res = result - third_number;
            document.getElementById("total").value = res;
        }
```

and i have written another function addNewQualification().
using that i am adding another row to the table

```
function addNewQualification(){
    var rowCount = $('#profDetHolder tr').length;
    var trData = '<tr id="'+rowCount+'row"><input type="hidden" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][id]" value="0" /><td><input type="text" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][billno]" value="<?php foreach ($Categories1 as $Category): echo $Category['Bill']['billno'] + 1; endforeach;?>" /></td><td><select id="cd" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][subcategory]" required x-moz-errormessage ="please select the category"><option>--select category--</option><?php foreach ($Categories as $Category): ?><option value="<?php echo $Category['Category']['category'] ?>"><?php echo $Category['Category']['category'];?></option><?php endforeach; ?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][qty]" onkeyup="add_numbers()" value="" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][amount]" value="" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][dis]" value="0" /></td><td><input type="text" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][total]" value="" /></td><td><select name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][user]" value=""  required ><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3<option></select></td><td><input type="hidden" name="data[User][qua]['+rowCount+'][cash]" value="<?php echo AuthComponent::user('username'); ?>" /></td><td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow('+rowCount+',0)" class="add_btn" style="font-size:20px;">-</button></td></tr>';
    $("#profDetHolder tr:last").after(trData);
}
```

here how can i add auto calculation to the newly added row ,using function add_number() i can only calculating thefields based on id here for the newly added row how can i add auto calculation for the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ids for the inputs are for all rows in that table everythime the same.

You may add `data-` before so you can get the data from the dataset.

Also you don't reference to which row should be calculated. Your `add_number` function don't know from which row the order is comming.

I've made as vanilla JavaScript example you may use:

```js
function add_number(inp) {
    var tr = inp.parentNode.parentNode;
    var first_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
    var second_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amount"]').value);
    var third_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="dis"]').value);

    var result = first_number * second_number;
    var res = result - third_number;
    tr.querySelector('[data-id="total"]').value = res ? res : '';
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-id="qty" name="data[User][qua][1][qty]" onkeyup="add_number(this)" value="" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE QTY')"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-id="amount" name="data[User][qua][1][amount]" onkeyup="add_number(this)" value="" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE AMOUNT')"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-id="dis" name="data[User][qua][1][dis]" onkeyup="add_number(this)" value="0"  required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE DISCOUNT')"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-id="total" name="data[User][qua][1][total]" value=""  required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ENTER THE TOTAL')"/></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery library and class based selectors eg.

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="field1" onkeyup="add_number(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="field2" onkeyup="add_number(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="total" /></td>
    </tr>


    function add_number(elem){
        var parent=$(elem).parent().parent(); //input>td>tr
        var sum=0;
        sum=$('.field1',parent).val()+$('.field2',parent).val();
        $('.total',parent).val(sum);
    }
```

Comment: can u please give some more clarity about the functionality  ,please!